# Magento 2: How to Show Discount Coupon Applied Code Product wise?

Tags: magento2, product, custom, discount, coupon

In Shopping Cart, I have 2 products. When I am applying the Promo Code it's going to apply on only 1 product as per the Shopping Cart/Promotion Rules.

**I would like to show discount code on basis of Product (Product based discount code)**

How to display product wise discount on **Shopping Cart/Mint Cart** & all other relevant pages? I want to achieve below thing please refer the below image.

[image]

Comment: I guess that would need an extension but I am interested to get that too.

Comment: did you find any solution ?